# Machine learning on classifying speech

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, k-nn, audio-recognition

So, I have 9k of 1 second wav files of a person speaking. These are labeled by whether the person speaking is wearing a face mask or not. I am supposed to come up with a machine learning model to classify these criteria.

So far I tried using KNN on the mfcc feature of the audio. This gets around 56% accuracy on test data.

I also tried to convert the wav files to jpg spectograms and apply a CNN. This one gets 60% accuracy on test data.

But I don't have that much experience, I am not sure which features of audio would best help to this problem.

Also, if you could recommend a machine learning model for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4,500 examples of each category, you’re doing better than random guessing. This sounds like a hard problem where the examples will have only subtle differences, so that’s an accomplishment. (I assume you’re doing some kind of out-of-sample testing.) Consider how you do in classifying perhaps 20 examples of each. I would be curious to hear how you do. This is quite a different problem if you get 38/40 than 20/40.

The way to apply a CNN, though, would be to convert to a spectrogram and then run the CNN on the spectrogram array. Converting to a literal picture is unnecessary and might harm performance. There are many ways to convert your signal to two dimensions of time-frequency space. You’ve probably tried a Fourier transform. Check out wavelets.

Since you have time series data, consider recurrent neural nets and long short-term memory. These can be combined with CNN. You will find examples of CNN/LSTM code on GitHub, I’d imagine.

You have a fairly small data set, however, for deep learning approaches. Consider simpler models like logistic regression. Your in-sample performance may suffer while improving out-of-sample performance.

Finally, consider a proper scoring rule like Brier score. Frank Harrell has written much about this on the statistics Stack, Cross Validated. Shamelessly, I will mention that you may be interested in a question of mine on CV where I somewhat challenge the idea of proper scoring rules when there is a hard decision to be made: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email. My example comes from NLP, but there could be a speech situation (say text dictation, where, at some point, you have to decide to print “dad” or “bad” or “bicycle”).

Comment: This is the CNN I applied. https://view.datalore.io/notebook/5iji7loSg4PUgRqH85epfp

Comment: I've tried a couple of CNN approaches from github, both seem to behave pretty bad, it is stuck at 50%. I've tried this https://github.com/cyber-gh/panotti and this https://github.com/micah5/pyAudioClassification

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations based on what I've done.
Here is a useful tutorial, which explains how to implement a CNN for wav files.

https://medium.com/gradientcrescent/urban-sound-classification-using-convolutional-neural-networks-with-keras-theory-and-486e92785df4.

In my case, it was overfitting and I wasn't able to fix that.

This simple NN model gave the best accuracy, of around 67%. [Here is the notebook used](https://github.com/jurgenarias/Portfolio/blob/master/Voice%20Classification/Code/Gender_Classifier/Gender_Classifier_NN.ipynb)

Also, as it was pointed previously, the training data set is fairly small for using neural networks. So in addition I've used [audio data augmentation](https://www.kaggle.com/ejlok1/audio-emotion-part-5-data-augmentation)  to avoid overfitting and increase train data size.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try a pretrained CNN to extract features, then do a simple classifier on top of that. [OpenL3](https://github.com/marl/openl3) for example is very easy to use, and performs pretty well on a range of tasks.
The classifier could be for example Logistic Regression, or Random Forest.